# Python Multithreading with requests

Tags: python, multithreading, request, python-multithreading

i have one scraper which initiate the "requestes" session and fetch some data, using a IPV6, i have now 10000 ip list, I have prepared it using threading, but its giving error.
Need support to find out the issue.

```
import requests, queue,threading, urllib3,jso,pandas as pd, os, time, datetime,inspect
num_threads = 2
root = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())))
with open (root+ "/ip_list.txt") as ips:
    device_ip = list(ips)
class Writer_Worker(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, queue, df, *args, **kwargs):
        if not queue:
            print("Device Queue not specified")
            exit(1)
        self.out_q = queue
        self.df = df
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    def run(self):
        while True:
            try:
                device_details = self.out_q.get(timeout=3)
            except queue.Empty:
                return
            self.df[device_details[0]] = device_details
            self.out_q.task_done()
class Worker(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, queue, out_queue, device_password, *args, **kwargs):
        if not queue:
            print("Device Queue not specified")
            exit(1)
        self.queue = queue
        self.pas = device_password
        self.out_q = out_queue
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    def run(self):
        while True:
            try:
                device_ip = self.queue.get(timeout=3)
            except queue.Empty:
                return
            self.connect_to_device_and_process(device_ip)
            self.queue.task_done()
    def connect_to_device_and_process(self, device_ip):
        st = str("Online")
        try:
            r = requests.post("https://["+device_ip+"]/?q=index.login&mimosa_ajax=1", {"username":"configure", "password":self.pas}, verify=False)
        except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
                st = str("Offline")
                self.out_q.put([device_ip,st,"","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""])
                return
        finally:
            if 'Online' in st:
                r = requests.get("https://["+device_ip+"]/cgi/dashboard.php", cookies=r.cookies, verify=False)
                if "Response [401]" in str(r):
                    st2 = str("Password Error")
                    self.out_q.put([device_ip,st2,"","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""])
                else:
                    data = json.loads(r.content.decode())
                    output5 = data ['config'] ['Spectrum_Power']
                    self.out_q.put([device_ip,st,output5['Auto_Power'].replace('2', 'Max Power').replace('1', 'Min Power').replace('0', 'off'),output5['AutoConfig']])
def main():
    start = time.time()
    urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)
    pas = input("Enter Device Password:")
    df =pd.DataFrame(columns = ["IP","Status","Auto_Power","AutoChannel"])
    q = queue.Queue(len(device_ip))
    for ip in device_ip:
        q.put_nowait(ip)
    out_q = queue.Queue(len(device_ip))
    Writer_Worker(out_q, df).start()
    for _ in range(num_threads):
        Worker(q, out_q, pas).start()
    q.join()
    print(df)
    df.to_excel('iBridge_C5x_Audit_Report.xlsx', sheet_name='Detail', index = False)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

below is the error while running the script, seeps I am unable to login to this device.
Any help is appreciable.

[image]

Comment: your `str2 = str("Password Error")` is wrong, `"Password Error" is already a string

Comment: @Theshape yeah write will do the correction, my main issue is how to make it multi-threading.

Answer (score 3):

You should use a thread pool that distributes the work between a fixed number of threads. This is a core feature of Python since version 3.2.

1. `from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor`
2. Define a function `perform(ip)` that performs the request for one ip
3. Set variable `numThreads` to the number of desired threads
4. Run the thread-pool executor:

```py
print(f'Using {numThreads} threads')
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=numThreads) as pool:
    success = all(pool.map(perform, ips))
```

Source: https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html

On that page you find an example even better tailored to your application: https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor-example

Comment: Thanks for help, but I am unable to implement this as per my requirement.
if possible can you modify my code. Thanks in advance.
I am a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

from threading import Thread

th = Thread(target=self.fill_imdb, args=(movies_info_part, "thread " + str(count)))
th.start()

fill_imdb is my method